# Comparison between Jones vectors and spin state vectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, polarization, quantum-states, bloch-sphere

I'm trying to learn about spinors by myself: I've found what it seems to me a very good series of videos on youtube which explains them starting from basic concepts and examples. Now, [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQOUhDEj4O8&list=PLJHszsWbB6hoOo_wMb0b6T44KM_ABZtBs&index=4), the author gives two examples of spinsors, Jones vectors and spin state vectors, since their state space is bound to the physical state by an angle doubling relation. Now, if I understand it right, Jones vectors can be represented as usual vectors (or rotating vectors) in physical state, where each of their component represents the x and y phase factor for the electric field:

$$ \vec{J} = \begin{bmatrix}
A^x e^{i \phi_x}\\ 
A^y e^{i \phi_y}
\end{bmatrix} = A^x e^{i \phi_x} \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} + A^y e^{i \phi_y} \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} = A^x e^{i \phi_x} \vec{H} + A^y e^{i \phi_y} \vec{V}$$

on the other hand, it is possible to say that overall phase can be ignored, hence $\vec{J}$ and $-\vec{J}$ represent the same polarization state. Therefore, as the author states, the verse doesn't matter and the state space of the polarization vectors can be represented by the Pointcaré sphere.

Now I find it more difficult to understand this concept for spin state vectors: it seems to me that their behaviour is the opposite of the Jones vector's one. The author carries a parallelism between the Pointcaré sphere for Jones vectors and Bloch sphere for spin states, but, as I understand, the *Block sphere represents physical space*, where the verse of the spin state vectors matters; in fact the two poles of the Block sphere are occupied by two of the standard basis spin states, that have - *physically* - an opposite verse, usually $\left\vert z \right\rangle$ and $\left\vert -z \right\rangle$. Now, assuming my understanding is correct up until this point, following the parallelism in state space the verse of spin state vectors should not matter, but, since it holds:

$$ \left\langle +x \vert -x \right\rangle = \left\langle -x \vert +x \right\rangle = 0$$
$$ \left\langle +y \vert -y \right\rangle = \left\langle -y \vert +y \right\rangle = 0$$
$$ \left\langle +z \vert -z \right\rangle = \left\langle -z \vert +z \right\rangle = 0$$

I could represent, for example, $\left\vert +z \right\rangle$ and $\left\vert -z \right\rangle$ as two orthogonal vector in their *state space*, the same for the other two couples of spin states. Now, how is it possible to say that, since the phase factor can be ignored, the verse of a state vector doesn't matter? I've tried to explain it to myself with the difference between $-\left\vert z \right\rangle \neq \left\vert -z \right\rangle$, but for hypotheses, it is assumed that for $\left\vert +z \right\rangle$ the spin is pointing up, and for $\left\vert -z \right\rangle$ it is pointing down, therefore the previous relation should not be false... I can't find the problem here: if the parallelism holds between polarization states and spin states, I should expect that the *state space* of spin states has the same characteristics of the *physical state* of the polarization vectors.

[image]

My questions are: is it correct to consider the Bloch sphere to be a geometric representation of the *physical space* for spin vectors? If so, how could the verse be ignored in the *spin state space*?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything seems good here except the link between the Bloch Sphere and what you call "physical space".  There are a number of reasons not to think of the Bloch Sphere as a sphere in physical space, but one of the best reasons is the very analogy you started with.  The Poincare Sphere is clearly not a good representation of physical space, and the Bloch sphere is also clearly analogous to the Poincare Sphere.

Some other reasons:  When you measure the z-component of the angular momentum of a spin-1/2 object, the uncertainty relations mean that you are not measuring the spin as pointing exactly in the z-direction, but rather at some angle to the z-axis.  The Bloch Sphere abstracts away this x- and y- component which aren't zero.  (Consider that $<S^2> = 3/4\, \hbar^2$, three times bigger than $<S_z^2>$.)

A more [subtle reason](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4999) is that the space of all spinors naturally lives on a 3-sphere -- the symmetry group is SU(2), not SO(3) -- but the Bloch sphere is only a 2-sphere.  The way to drop from a 3-sphere to a 2-sphere is something called a Hopf Fibration, which roughly maps to removing the global phase.  But evidently this changes the global geometry:  a 3-sphere is not just a circle mapped to every point on a 2-sphere.

The conclusion, which I think you've already almost reached, is that Bloch spheres aren't physical.

Comment: Ok, I might have understood. One last clarification: if I can't think of the Bloch sphere as a sphere in physical space, to which spaces do the angle doubling relation that characterizes spin state vectors apply? I guess that it applies between the Bloch sphere and the vector space where opposite vector states are orhogonal...

Comment: Mathematicians use the term "double cover" to refer to the relationship between these two representations, and it naturally happens whenever you move from a 3D vector space to the space of all possible rotations of those vectors.  "Orthogonal" states are most naturally viewed as literally-orthogonal, perpendicular to each other, but that perspective of spinors requires a 3-sphere, which is hard to visualize.  The alternate representation of the Bloch Sphere is easier to picture, but the linked paper argues that it is really a reduced space of rotations, tossing out important phase information.